# Several questions about overload the 'copyElement' method in subclasses of 'matlab.mixin.Copyable'

Tags: matlab, matlab-class

The [`matlab.mixin.Copyable` page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.mixin.copyable-class.html?s_tid=srchtitle_site_search_1_matlab.mixin.Copyable) describes the following information:

1. The copy method makes a shallow copy of the object.
2. `copyElement` is a Protected Method that the copy method uses to perform the copy operation on each object in the input array
3. MATLAB® does not call copy recursively on any handles contained in property values.
4. The copy method copies data without calling the class constructor or property set functions. It therefore produces no side effects.

There is  four questions：

1. *The `copy` method makes a shallow copy of the object.* But in overload `copyElement` code use `copy` to make a deep copy of the `DeepCp` object ([this page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.mixin.copyable-class.html?s_tid=srchtitle_site_search_1_matlab.mixin.Copyable)). Why？So, can the copy method perform deep copying ? Or not

   ```matlab
   methods(Access = protected)
         % Override copyElement method:
         function cpObj = copyElement(obj)
            % Make a shallow copy of all four properties
            cpObj = copyElement@matlab.mixin.Copyable(obj);
            % Make a deep copy of the DeepCp object
            cpObj.DeepObj = copy(obj.DeepObj);
         end
      end
   ```

   By running the following code, you will notice that as long as it's an object of the `matlab.mixin.Copyable` class, using copy will achieve deep copying. Therefore, is it not an incorrect conclusion to say, "The copy method makes a shallow copy of the object"?

   ```matlab
   classdef  DeepCp < matlab.mixin.Copyable
       properties
           DpProp
       end
       methods
           function obj = DeepCp(val)
               obj.DpProp=val;
           end
       end
   end
   ```

   Run the following command in the command line:

   ```matlab
   A=DeepCp(7);
   B=copy(A);
   A.DpProp=222;
   B
   ```
2. *`copyElement` is a Protected Method.* So, is it necessary to declare `Access = protected` when overloading `copyElement`? Is it always required to do so? Do you have to redeclare all method attributes when overloading built-in methods in MATLAB?
3. "[copyElement](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/matlab/ref/matlab.mixin.copyable-class.html?s_tid=srchtitle_site_search_1_matlab.mixin.Copyable) is a protected method that the copy method uses to **perform the copy operation** on each object in the input array"

- Since 'copyElement' ultimately performs the copying work, why does
  referencing the parent class's 'copyElement' result in a shallow copy,
  while using 'copy' directly results in a deep copy? Does using 'copy'
  directly not ultimately invoke 'copyElement' as well?

  ```
    % Make a shallow copy of all four properties
    cpObj = copyElement@matlab.mixin.Copyable(obj);
    % Make a deep copy of the DeepCp object
    cpObj.DeepObj = copy(obj.DeepObj);
  ```

4. *MATLAB® does not call copy recursively on any handles contained in property values.* Since the copy method is sealed, it cannot be overloaded or defined. So how can a situation with recursive calls to copy occur? For instance, in the case of get methods, when you define a get method within a class, it may reference the class's properties, creating a possibility of recursive calls to the get method. Therefore, it is explicitly stated that there should not be a recursive call situation in get methods.
5. *The copy method copies data without calling the class constructor or property set functions.* It therefore produces no side effects. What built-in methods call "the class constructor or property set functions"? What are the side effects of calling the class constructor or property set functions?

Comment: [The bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77079050/timeline) attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.

Comment: @cris-luengo at >50k rep you should be aware that a question asking 5 separate questions is not worth editing into a nicely formatted list, but should be voted for closure. It clearly "needs focus."

Comment: @miken32 it looks like my close vote aged away.

Comment: @miken32 The reason I put the five questions together is because they are highly related. At least two of the questions are raised in a unified statement about the official MATLAB documentation.

Comment: This kind of discussion would be better taken to Matlab's extensive forums. SO is more about solving concrete (single) problems with your code than wide-ranging conversations about programming practices.